# Separation and width of caption with captionbeside

Tags: captions, margins, koma-script

I'm trying to control the typesetting of a caption beside a figure when using the `captionbeside` environment of the KOMA Script packages. The `\setcapwidth` command doesn't work when using `captionbeside`. Figures are placed to the left of the page, with a caption to the right(top) side. Captions are supposed to be 4cm wide, and allowed to extend into the (4cm wide) margin. However they are stretched to the full `\textwidth` when the figure is small, for large figures it works reasonably well. I'm also clueless about the separation/margin between the figure and the caption, which I'd like to set exaclty to `\marginparsep` (0.4cm in my case). Example so far:

```
\documentclass[captions=topbeside]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
% Works here
\begin{figure}
\setcapwidth{4cm}
\setcapindent{1em}
\rule{4cm}{6cm}
\caption{Long caption that is 4cm wide}
\end{figure}
% Not here
\begin{figure}
\setcapwidth{4cm}
\setcapindent{1em}
\begin{captionbeside}{Long caption supposed to be 4cm wide}[o]
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\totalheight\relax}{
    \rule{4cm}{6cm}
    }
\end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I also tried the `sidecap` package, possibly together with the `caption` package, but those also don't set the caption width.

**EDIT:** Another posibility:

```
\begin{figure}
\mbox{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\totalheight}{%
        \rule{\textwidth}{4cm}%
    }%
    \hspace{0.4cm}%
    \parbox{4.13cm}{\captionof{figure}{Caption that is 4cm wide}}
    }
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated Answer!**

Please try this new changed MWE:

```
\documentclass[captions=topbeside]{scrartcl} % topbeside

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

% Not here
\begin{figure}
\setcapindent{1em}
\begin{captionbeside}{Long caption supposed to be 4cm wide}[o][8cm]%[5cm]
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\totalheight\relax}{
    \rule{4cm}{6cm}
    }
\end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\setcapindent{1em}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.4cm}  % <========================================
\begin{captionbeside}{Long caption supposed to be 4cm wide}[o][8cm]%[5cm]
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\totalheight\relax}{
    \rule{4cm}{6cm}
    }
\end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\setcapindent{1em}
\begin{captionbeside}{Long caption supposed to be 4cm wide}[o][8cm][5cm]
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\baselineskip-\totalheight\relax}{
    \rule{4cm}{6cm}
    }
\end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With KOMA-Script the meaning of the environment `captionbeside` is: 
`\begin{captionbeside}[Toc title]{Title}[Position][total length][offset from left]`

See now line 11 in my MWE: `\begin{captionbeside}{Long caption supposed to be 4cm wide}[o][8cm]%[5cm]`

The given width here is the sum of your image width (4cm) and the caption width (4cm), resulting 8cm.  `o` give the position of the caption: outside. offset is not used here.  (You did not use the two latest options ...)

The second image shows the same with a changed space between image and caption. 
See line 20:  `\setlength{\columnsep}{1.4cm}`
You can change the `\columnsep` as shown (I took 1.4cm to make the change visible).

You can find the relevant code for example in line 4110 of `scrartcl.cls` (definition of `\newenvironment*{captionbeside}` in line 4103 ff).

The third image is the same as the first, but has an offset of 5cm.  That means image and captions are moved 5 cm to the right (it always starts on the left side!).

You can find this information in the documentation of KOMA-Script, for example in my german book on page 153, chapter 3.20 "floatings for tables and figures". Sorry, I do not have the english book.  You can also check `texdoc KOMA-Script`.

See the result:

[image]

Comment: This is how I "solved" it for larger figures, where I need to do this to extend the caption into the margin. I was just hoping for a more "automated" solution where I don't have to explicitly enter the width of the figure (+4cm). But I guess I won't get around this. So the only thing missing is the separation between the figure and the caption. I can't find the length in any docs, so I guess I'll have to dive into the source.